# Can we still launch a foreground service with extended Service class or we should move to workmanager?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting issue regarding foreground service is that some time foreground being killed by os so should i resolve Service class issue or move to workmanager . i have completed the  application and only getting a single os issue  suggestion required thanks .
// this is the service class

```
          class SmsService  : Service() {
   private var wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock? = null
private lateinit var smsScheduler : SmsScdeduler
private var isServiceStarted  = false
private   var    notificationBuilder : NotificationCompat.Builder?=null
private var serviceScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
private var  notificationManager : NotificationManager?=null


fun isServiceRunning():Boolean{
    return isServiceStarted }

companion object{
    const  val MESSAGE_ID: String ="messageId"
    const val USER_ID:String ="userId"
    const val DELIVERED: String ="sb.app.messageschedular.sms_schedulers.DELIVERYKEY"
    const val ADD_SERVICE = "sb.spp.message_scheduler.add"
    const val DELETE_SERVICE ="sb.spp.message_scheduler.delete"
    const val Add_kEY ="ADD_KEY"
    const val SENT ="sb.app.messageschedular.sms_schedulers.SENT"
    private  const val channelId = "default_notification_channel_id"
    private const val NOTIFICATION_ID =1995L
}

/************* Delivery BroaddCast ENd  **************/



override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()


    smsScheduler =  SmsScdeduler.getInstance(this )




    val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    notificationBuilder  = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(sb.app.messageschedular.R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Message Scheduled")
        //  .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)

}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    showNotification(NOTIFICATION_ID)

    wakeLock =
        (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
            newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "EndlessService::lock").apply {
                acquire()
            }
        }

    println("intent ${intent }")
    isServiceStarted =true

    if(intent!=null) {
        val action = intent?.action
        val sms = intent?.getParcelableExtra<Sms>(Add_kEY)
        schedule(sms!!)
    }else{

        serviceScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            smsScheduler.reSchedule()
        }


    }

    return START_STICKY }

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun showNotification(messageid:Long ) {

    notificationManager  = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, "test1", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        channel.description = "test otificaiton"
        notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    this.startForeground(messageid.toInt() ,notificationBuilder!!.build())


}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return LocalBinder() }



inner class LocalBinder : Binder(){
    fun getService(): SmsService = this@SmsService
}



override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    isServiceStarted =false
    if( serviceScope.isActive){
        println("Service Scope is cancelled ")
        serviceScope.cancel() }

 
}




}

fun finish() {
    println("service finished ")

    println("Stop  self")

    println("Stop foreground service")
    stopForeground(true )

    println("service state  false ")
    isServiceStarted =false
    stopSelf()
}




}


// calling service 
                fun scheduleService(sms: Sms) {
    if(!mService.isServiceRunning()){

        val intent = Intent(this , SmsService::class.java)
        intent.action = SmsService.ADD_SERVICE
        intent.putExtra(SmsService.Add_kEY, sms)

      
   ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this.applicationContext,intent)

      }
```

/// Permission of Service

```
    <service android:name=".service.SmsService"

        android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"
        />
```

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do.  WorkManager is good for things that are periodic background processing and can happen at a slightly fuzzy time in the future.  Foreground services are for when you need to stay resident now, for example Uber using one to keep its GPS tracking alive while you're waiting for a car, even if you switched to another app in the meantime.  But if you're expecting a foreground service to stay around forever so you can always do stuff in the background, it doesn't work that way anymore.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks you so much so it means that it is myth to say that service class is deprecated we can still  use it in some situations?

Comment: Service is definitely not deprecated.  It is more limited in its use than it was in the past, particularly background services can only remain resident for a brief period without your app being in the foreground.  But it still has uses.

Comment: @GabeSechan bro is it normal that os kills foreground service and it get restarted if i pass STICKY flag

Comment: Are you setting is up as a foreground service properly?  To do that, you need to start it with startForegroundService AND the Service must call startForeground() relatively quickly-  generally in its onStartCommand function

Comment: @GabeSechan i have mentioned the code could you check it out